# AWS CLI throwing "No module named 'botocore.parameters'" error?

Tags: 14.04, python, pip, aws

I installed the AWS CLI [using the instructions provided that suggest using PIP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html).  After the installation when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
[21:03:50] ip-10-0-0-115:awscli-1.2.9.egg-info $ aws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 44, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 53, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.ec2addcount import ec2_add_count
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/customizations/ec2addcount.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore.parameters import StringParameter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.parameters'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 44, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 53, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.ec2addcount import ec2_add_count
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/customizations/ec2addcount.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore.parameters import StringParameter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.parameters'
```

When I try to manually install the `boto` package it says it's already installed.  What could be causing this error?  Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get around this was to use the bundle installer instructions found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html

After installing using those instructions I was finally able to get it running.